# Cannot read property 'requestAnimationFrame' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, requestanimationframe, echarts

After I've included "echarts-for-react" library to my project, I've started getting **Cannot read property 'requestAnimationFrame' of undefined** error.

The interesting part is that I'm only getting this error on **Windows 10**. When I open the project on **OS X**, everything works as expected. I'm using Chrome version 64.0.3282.186 on both OSs. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLBp1.png)

I'm using:
react: v15.4.1,
webpack: v1.14.0

Do you have any suggestions about this problem?

Comment: Which browsers are you using BTW?

Comment: Provide code, or your question will be deleted

Comment: I'm using Chrome 64.0.3282.186 on both OSs

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers don't support requestAnimationFrame.

You can use a polyfill like [this here](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) which will use a setTimeout if requestAnimationFrame is not available

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of `echarts-for-react`.

Related issue, ref: [Running into a '__resizeListeners__' of undefined with react and Semantic-UI accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634759/running-into-a-resizelisteners-of-undefined-with-react-and-semantic-ui-acc)